zig error: no module named 'shared' available within module test
I'm learning zig and stuck with it's import system.
Here's my project tree:
├── build.zig
├── build.zig.zon
└── src
    ├── foo
    │   ├── bar.zig
    │   └── foo.zig
    ├── main.zig
    ├── root.zig
    └── shared
        ├── shared.zig
        └── util.zig

Zig doesn't (yet?) have a builtin module/package system, so if I import
const util = @import("../shared/util.zig");

inside bar.zig and run test:
zig test **redacted**/zig-modules/src/foo/bar.zig -O Debug

I'll get a error:
bar.zig:1:22: error: import of file outside module path: '../shared/util.zig'

So I add 2 modules to default build.zig generated with zig init:
const fooModule = b.addModule("foo", .{
    .root_source_file = b.path("src/foo/foo.zig"),
});

const sharedModule = b.addModule("shared", .{
    .root_source_file = b.path("src/shared/shared.zig"),
});

lib.root_module.addImport("foo", fooModule);
lib.root_module.addImport("shared", sharedModule);

exe.root_module.addImport("foo", fooModule);
exe.root_module.addImport("shared", sharedModule);

lib_unit_tests.root_module.addImport("foo", fooModule);
lib_unit_tests.root_module.addImport("shared", sharedModule);

Now when I'm importing const util = @import("shared").util; and running test I get another error:
bar.zig:1:22: error: no module named 'shared' available within module test

shared.zig:
pub const util = @import("util.zig");

I searched a solution in bun, tigerbeetle and some other projects, but haven't succeeded to adopt it in my code. Could someone provide a clue or project example of how to cook zig 0.13.0 modules?

If you have a test step that depends on lib_unit_tests, you can invoke zig build test, rather than testing each file independently. AFAIK, modules may only be created within Zig's build system (aka build.zig), and are not known to individual files without it. Take a look at the build system documentation for more info: https://ziglang.org/learn/build-system/

Zig has a module/package system. What you're trying to do can essentially be achived with the default build.zig that zig init generates. You don't need to manually add shared and foo as modules if they are in the src directory. All you need to do is run zig build [step]. For example, zig build test to run all the tests in the project, or zig build run to compile and run the project, or just zig build to just compile the project.

I need zig test command to run how to do that?

Then I guess you need to give it all of the dependencies needed to build a particular file. E.g. zig test src/foo/bar.zig src/shared/util.zig ...
